# Php script that outputs code for me

Tags: php, output

i want to make a php script that outputs specific code. I have this game where i develop alot of things for but many of that is the same sort of code. like classnames.

so i want to make a php script where i can fill the case, and checkbox what classnames with what price. for example.

It has to output something like this:

```
case "civ_car":<--- changeable
{
    _return = 
    [
        ["B_Quadbike_01_F",3333],<<---- classname followed by a price 
        ["C_Hatchback_01_F",8333],
        ["C_Offroad_01_F",16666],
        ["C_SUV_01_F",40000],
        ["C_Van_01_transport_F",50000],
        ["C_Hatchback_01_sport_F",53333]<<------ no , here
    ];
};
```

the prices are so strange because they will be multiplied by 1,5 in the game.

but sometimes it needs to look a little diffrent like this:

```
case "med_shop":<<---- also want this to be changeable
{
    _return = [
        ["C_Hatchback_01_F",5000]<<--- these dont need a ; at the end
    ];

    if(__GETC__(life_mediclevel) >= 2) then <<---- also wanna be able to change the life_mediclevel and the statement behind it.
    {
        _return pushBack ["C_Van_01_box_F",45224];<<---- these need a ; at the end
    };

    if(__GETC__(life_mediclevel) >= 3) then 
    {
        _return pushBack ["C_SUV_01_F",50000];
        _return pushBack ["C_Offroad_01_F",50000];
    };

    if(__GETC__(life_mediclevel) >= 4) then 
    {
        _return pushBack ["C_Hatchback_01_sport_F",5000];
    };
};
```

How would a php script for this look like? if you guys could push me in the right direction i could do the rest. IF you require JavaScript and/or html 5 that is no problem.

Thanks in advance,

Joey

Answer (score 0):

[call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) should be able to help you.

Comment: Could you send me on my way some more? like a basic script?

Comment: To be honest I don't understand your code. I would, just use call_user_func("B_Quadbike_01_F", 3333) instead of the _return pushback stuff. It doesn't look like PHP and I cant find any reference to those keywords in regards to PHP.

Comment: Im sorry i should have mentioned that it is SQF, language used by real virtuality 4. I want the php code to output that.

Comment: Ah, sorry. You're on your own then. Sorry for wasting your time. However, you should update your tags and question to reflect this realization.